# how to reply to sender email using php contact form

Tags: php

I am trying to adjust my code to able to reply to sender email from PHP contact form. please check my code below to give advise. Thank you

```
<?php

$marke = $_POST['marke'];
$modell = $_POST['modell'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
$adresse = $_POST['adresse'];
$telefon = $_POST['telefon'];
$email = $_POST['email'];

$to = 'myemail@gmail.com';
$from = 'myemail@gmail.com';
$subject = 'Contact Form';


$body = "marke: $marke\n modell: $modell\n name: $name\n adresse: $adresse\n 
email: $email\n telefon: $telefon\n";

?>

<?php
if ($_POST['submit']) {
if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) { 
    header("Location: http://www.website.com/sent.php");
} else { 
    echo '<p>Oops! An error occurred. Try sending your message again.</p>'; 
}
}
?>
```

Comment: What problem are you having?

Comment: @RussJ I want to be able to reply to the sender directly when I receive the form as an email from the website

Comment: Then you will have to obtain the user's e-mail address somehow, most likely through a text field. Note that you won't be able to verify that the e-mail the enter is correct since e-mail protocols prohibit that (the only way to verify that an e-mail address is accurate on another domain you don't have access to is to send a message and see if it bounces back).

Comment: Set this property as the "from" in the mail() call

Comment: @RussJ as you can see in my PHP code there is a text field to obtain user email address. I want a method where I can reply to that email directly from the email I receive.

Comment: You should just be able to hit "Reply" in your e-mail client. When you receive the e-mail, the "From" should be the sender's e-mail.

Comment: @RussJ how to specify in my PHP code to have "From" as the sender's email

Comment: Create a text field named "senderEmail" or something similar, then where you _POST your other vars, set your $from=$_POST['senderEmail'];

Comment: $from= $_POST['email']; I tried this. now i have the sender email on top of the message but not as a reply to

Comment: Reply-to should be part of your header: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First make headers

```
$headers = "From: $from\r\nReply-to: $email";
```

Than fix calling of mail function to be

```
mail ($to, $subject, $body, $headers)
```

Didn't tried it from times when it was PHP 4 but it will probably work as you expected...

**Addition:**
I just checked on php.net... go to this url http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php and check **"Example #2 Sending mail with extra headers."**